# Find place of all same objects in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

How i can find **all place of a same objects** in **list** like :

```
>>>a=['a','a','b','c','a']
>>>findplace('a')
>>>[0,1,4]
```

Comment: Can you please share your current attempts to solve this problem?

Comment: Use enumerate and list comprehension. Try it first yourself. Please.